# Group by date query in Azure DB

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have column(x) with "**2020-07-24 19:08:10.843**" format.

Requirement: Need to find the row count per day basis.

Comment: For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query that will work on all Sql Server versions:

`SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ColumnName)) as ColumnName, COUNT(*) FROM TableName GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ColumnName));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT CAST(Column as Date) YourDate, Count(1)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CAST(Column as Date)
```

By converting the column to a `date` column, you remove the time part. So you can aggregate (count) by date instead of datetime.